# How to check whether a user is registered and enrolled in fabric-ca server using cli commands?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have already started the fabric-ca server. And enrolled the bootstrap entity. Also registered and enrolled a user.

Now I have the fabric-sdk code to check whether a user is registered and enrolled in the fabric-ca server. I need to know, is it possible to check the same using cli command.

Comment: You should probably use the Hyperledger RocketChat or mailing list(s) for these types of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fabric-ca-client identity list --id ${ENROLLID}`

`fabric-ca-client certificate list --id ${ENROLLID}`

Comment: I wanted to know how to validate whether a user is registered and enrolled in the server. The above commands returns the list of users those who were already enrolled.

Comment: What do you mean by validate  ... the first command above will only show a user if it has been registered and the second if  it's been enrolled.

Comment: if(user && user.isEnrolled) {
   if (isJson && isJson === true) {
    var response = {
     success: true,
     secret: user._enrollmentSecret,
     message: username + ' enrolled Successfully',
    };
    return response;
   }
  } else {
   throw new Error('User was not enrolled ');
  }                                                                                                                                                         Here you see, I have an if condition to check whether the user is enrolled and registered. The same thing i have to do using cli commands.

Comment: The `user.isEnrolled` actually simply checks to see if the enrollment certificate exists locally; it does not actually call any Fabric CA APIs.  So you really would not use the fabric-ca-client to check this; you'd simply check that the `msp` directory generated by the fabric-ca-client exists and has the crypto material in it.

My answer above includes the commands to check with the CA if the user is registered and if the user has even been enrolled.